# Find closest number to one number in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a database like this:

```
people
id      name       zip
1       bill       84058
2       susan      90001
3       john       64354
```

Say I have an input number of 65432

I want to write a query something like this:

`SELECT * FROM people WHERE zip CLOSEST TO 65432 LIMIT 1`

And get `john` as the row returned.

I can't find what the closest to command is in Postgresql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `ABS` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
ORDER BY ABS(65432 - zip) ASC LIMIT 1
```